# Ruby stop and move to next iteration of for loop

Tags: ruby, loops, for-loop, escaping, iteration

I have a for loop with an if elsif statement inside. On the first if, if the condition is met I want it to stop there and go on to the next iteration of the loop.

This is a very simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,"x"]
for i in 0..(array.count -1)
    if array[i] == "x"
        #start next for loop iteration without executing the elsif
    elsif array[i] < 3
        puts "YAY!"
    end
end
```

What I am exactly trying to do is iterating through an array which all but one of the elements are integers but one of them is a string. On the string element, I need the loop (whatever kind is best) to skip the rest of the code and go to the next iteration of the loop. This is important because the second if statement uses an 'array_element < 11 condition' so if it runs that on the string element I get "comparison of String with 11 failed"

so I would want arr[x][3] this is what i tried but it gives me 8 8 8 8 instead of a single 8.

```
arr = [[1,2,3,"4"], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]] 

    arr.each{|x| 
    x.each {|i| 
        next if x[3].instance_of? String 
        if x[3] < 12 puts x[3] 
        end 
} 
}
```

Ok this works!! Thank you iAmRubuuu!!

```
arr = [1,2,3,"4"], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,"16"], [17,18,19,20]]

arr.each_with_index{|x, i| 

    next if x.last.instance_of? String

    if x.last < 21
    puts x.last
    end
}
```

give me the output

```
8
12
20
```

Comment: edited original question

Comment: I have added one answer,hope that would help you out.

Comment: I have given you the answer,try to understand that,do things properly.

Comment: Yea iAmRubuuu your help is very appreciated! my program is coming along nicely now. Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `for in`, use `each`.

```
(0..10).each do |i|
  next if i == 5

  if i == 10
    puts "YAY!"
  end
end
```

Comment: ahh ok ok so the "next" is saying to move on to the next iteration if the condition is met? Do you think you could explain to me piece by piece what your code is doing?

Comment: actually this code is giving me the same error as before... let me explain exactly what I am trying to do. I am iterating through an array which all but one of the elements are integers but one of them is a string. On the string elements I need the loop (whatever kind is best) to skip the rest of the code and go to the next iteration of the loop. This is important because the second if statement uses an 'array_element < 11 condition' so if it runs that on the string element I get "comparison of String with 11 failed"

Comment: @kingweaver88: you want to skip the string? Use this: `next if i.is_a?(String)`

Answer (score 2):

As per your edit, hope the below one you are looking for:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, "11", 11]
arr.each do |x|
  next if x.instance_of? String
  puts "#{x} is #{x.class}"
end
```

*Output:*

```
1 is Fixnum
2 is Fixnum
3 is Fixnum
11 is Fixnum
```

**EDIT**

Code:

```
arr = [[1,2,3,"4"], [4,5,6,7], [8,9,10,11]] 

arr.each{|x|
x.each{ |i|
next if i.instance_of? String
puts "#{i} is #{i.class}"
}
}
```

*Output:*

```
1 is Fixnum
2 is Fixnum
3 is Fixnum
4 is Fixnum
5 is Fixnum
6 is Fixnum
7 is Fixnum
8 is Fixnum
9 is Fixnum
10 is Fixnum
11 is Fixnum
```

**V_1(from your first comment in my answer post)**

```
arr = [[1,2,3,"4"], [4,5,6,7], [8,9,10,11]] 
puts arr[1].last,arr.last.last
```

*Output:*

```
7
11
```

**V_2(from your first comment in my answer post)**

```
arr = [[1,2,3,"4"], [4,5,6,7], [8,9,10,11]] 
arr.each_with_index{ |x,i|
next if i == 0
#p x,i
p "last element of inner array:#{x.last}"
}
```

*Output:*

```
"last element of inner array:7"
"last element of inner array:11"
```

Comment: ok let me complicate things a bit more to see how this would scale for my purposes. imagine that you have an array of arrays so what if 
arr = [[1,2,3,"4"], [4,5,6,7], [8,9,10,11]] 
and I want to iterate on 
arr[x][3] --> output should be 7 11, how would I do this?

Comment: hmm I see what your doing here except that you're iterating through every element. Would this work if I wanted only the 4th element in each of the inner arrays? so I would want arr[x][3] this is what i tried but it gives me 8 8 8 8 instead of a single 8.

    arr = [[1,2,3,"4"], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]]

 arr.each{|x| 
 x.each {|i|

  next if x[3].instance_of? String

  if x[3] < 12
   puts x[3]
  end
    }
    }

Comment: Ok your version 2 solution sort of does what I need it to... however I am a little confused on what is happening there, do you mind explaining what is happening with the .each_with_index ? in my actual code the string may pop up randomly in the inside array it is not always going to be the array at index 0... how would I do this?

Comment: I tried replacing the i == 0 with i.instance_of? String but I get the error `<': comparison of String with 12 failed (ArgumentError)

Comment: ahhh if I use x.last.instance_of? String in place of i == 0 then it works!! Thank you very very much for your help!!

Comment: @kingweaver88 Then why didn't accept my answer and up-vote me? :) if you satisfied then accept my answer. :)